# grep - highlight inside a highlight

Tags: command-line, colors, grep

I'm facing difficulties while trying to multicolor-highlight matches using grep's color environment.

After I stumbled across [Colored grep](http://www.jefftk.com/p/colored-grep), I found it very useful to highlight multiple pattern in a single run.
So I set up the alias' as told, but then I came across following problem:

```
echo "Im looking for KeyWords" | grep 'KeyWords' --color=always | green-grep 'Word'
```

results in

Im looking for *Key* **Word**s (italic=red, bold=green)

where the "s" is not highlighted red, because `grep` sets the color environment back to normal after the end of a match.

Is there any way to realize this with `grep`, or am I facing a wall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't hit a wall, but you've hit a `|`!  (So unfortunately, no, you cannot do that without a major re-write of the `grep` source code.)

However, I like the idea, so if you want, feel free to file a bug at the FSF, or if you don't want to go through the effort, I'll file the bug for you!  (just drop a comment)

---

Fantastic question! I've already added:

```
alias grey-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;30' grep --color=always"
alias red-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;31' grep --color=always"
alias green-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;32' grep --color=always"
alias yellow-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;33' grep --color=always"
alias blue-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;34' grep --color=always"
alias magenta-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;35' grep --color=always"
alias cyan-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;36' grep --color=always"
alias white-grep="GREP_COLOR='1;37' grep --color=always"
```

to my `bash.bashrc` file!

Answer (score 0):

This way works only if the grep functions return a single line, otherwise the piping cancel susbequent lines
I was trying to use egrep with five regex expression, whith espressions in different line in original file (it's a log with a lot of info); so far i can change the colour, but not get a different color for every regex filter:

```
cat logfile egrep 'regex1|regex2|regex3|regex4|regex5'
```